# how to call .Net web-service from google app?

Tags: java, .net, web-services, google-app-engine

Is it possible to develop and host a dot net webservice on some location say www.example.com/test.asmx

and call it from googleapp engine.

Comment: what language are you writing it in?

Comment: I want to develop a web-service in C# language and call it in google app engine java language

Comment: Have a look at http://www.asp.net/web-api It's something you might be asking/looking for.

Answer (score 2):

AppEngine provides the [URLFetch](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/) service for making calls from your AppEngine application to external web services or resources.

Comment: So how to call that webserice if test method have one parameter, is the following code is correct URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/test.asmx");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("username", "khan");

Comment: @Khan, don't post code in comments. That won't work. Edit your question and put the code there. Also, I'm not going to test your code for you. Try it out and see if it works for you.

Comment: is the same way we can call a webservice in google-app-engine as in java example in reference URL